# Why is WebRequestContextImpl annotated as Primary, can it be removed in next release?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

We are building a DXA-application that has to land on a platform where host rewriting takes place. Because of this, some DXA functions that use the domain of the request will function incorrect. An example of this incorrect functioning is sitemap.xml, which uses WebRequestContext.getBaseUrl().

We want to override the WebRequestContextImpl.getBaseUrl(), but because WebRequestContextImpl is annotated as Primary, this is not possible.

Is there a special reason why WebRequestContextImpl is annotated as Primary, and if not, can @Primary be removed from this class in the next release?